# Elastic Search Data is not updating after Insert And Delete in symfony

Tags: php, foselasticabundle, symfony6

hey there I'm trying to do crud operation using Symfony and elastic search, crud is working fine but when I insert or delete data then elastic search data is not updating by self I need to run populate command every time. can you help with this?

here is my fos_elastica.yml file.

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        reply:
            properties:
                category:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        title: ~
            persistence:
                driver: orm
                model: App\Entity\Reply
```

and here is my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\CP\Support\Replies;

use App\Controller\CP\AbstractCPController;
use App\Entity\Reply;
use App\Form\Filter\ReplyFilterType;
use App\Form\ReplyType;
use App\Repository\ReplyRepository;
use App\Security\Enum\AdminPermission;
use App\Security\Routing\DenyAccessUnlessGranted;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder;
use Elastica\Util;
use Throwable;

#[Route('/support/pre-defined-replies/reply')]
#[DenyAccessUnlessGranted(permission: AdminPermission::MANAGE_PRE_DEFINED_REPLIES_REPLY)]
class ReplyController extends AbstractCPController
{
    private ReplyRepository $replyRepository;

    public function __construct(ReplyRepository $replyRepository)
    {
        $this->replyRepository = $replyRepository;
    }

    #[Route('/', name: 'cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(TransformedFinder $replyFinder, Request $request): Response
    {
        $searchTerm = '';
        $filterForm = $this->createForm(ReplyFilterType::class);
        $filterForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($filterForm->isSubmitted()) {
            $category = $filterForm->get('category')->getData();
            $searchTerm = $category->getName();
        }
        $search = Util::escapeTerm($searchTerm);
        $results = $replyFinder->find($search);
        return $this->render('support/pre_defined_replies/reply/index.html.twig', [
            'replies' => $results,
            'form' => $filterForm->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/new', name: 'cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $reply = new Reply();
        $form = $this->createForm(ReplyType::class, $reply);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            try {
                $this->replyRepository->add($reply, true);
                $this->addFlash('success', 'successfully created new reply.');
            } catch (Throwable $throwable) {
                $this->addFlash('danger', 'fail create new reply.');
            }
            return $this->redirectToRoute('cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('support/pre_defined_replies/reply/new.html.twig', [
            'reply' => $reply,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }


    #[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, Reply $reply): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ReplyType::class, $reply);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            try {
                $this->replyRepository->add($reply, true);
                $this->addFlash('success', 'successfully updated reply');
            } catch (Throwable $throwable) {
                $this->addFlash('danger', 'failed to update reply');
            }
            return $this->redirectToRoute('cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('support/pre_defined_replies/reply/edit.html.twig', [
            'reply' => $reply,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{id}/delete', name: 'cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_delete', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function delete(Request $request, Reply $reply): Response
    {
        $csrfTokenReply = (string) $request->request->get('csrf');

        $status = false;
        $errorMessage = null;

        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('reply', $csrfTokenReply)) {
            try {
                $this->replyRepository->remove($reply);
                $status = true;
                $this->addFlash('danger', 'category successfully deleted');
            } catch (\Throwable $e) {
                $errorMessage = 'An error occurred when deleting category from DB.';
            }
        } else {
            $errorMessage = 'Invalid CSRF token';
        }

        return new JsonResponse(['status' => $status, 'errorMessage' => $errorMessage]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use refresh indexes in elastic search for update data

first we need to bind new parameter in service.yaml file

```
    App\Controller\CP\Support\Replies\ReplyController:
    tags: [ controller.service_arguments ]
    bind:
        FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder $replyFinder: '@fos_elastica.finder.reply'
        FOS\ElasticaBundle\Elastica\Index: '@fos_elastica.index.reply'
```

then we can use simply like this in controller to refresh indexes

#[Route('/new', name: 'cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new(Request $request, Index $replyIndex): Response
{
$reply = new Reply();
$form = $this->createForm(ReplyType::class, $reply);
$form->handleRequest($request);

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        try {
            $this->replyRepository->add($reply, true);
            $this->addFlash('success', 'successfully created new reply.');
            $replyIndex->refresh();
        } catch (Throwable $throwable) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'fail create new reply.');
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('cp_support_pre_defined_replies_reply_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('support/pre_defined_replies/reply/new.html.twig', [
        'reply' => $reply,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```